# Change product position programmatically

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, api

I'm using a magento api script to change the product status.
i want to add to the script an update that will change all the positions of the product in all of the related categories to 0.
what would be the best approach for this:

**This is the script that i'm using in a nutshell**

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app ()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
umask(0);
$sku = $_GET['sku'];
$id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product->getId(), 0, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Asking for a fully functional script rarely gets a lot of response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to do it is with direct queries. Not the best but certainly the fastest.
All the product positions are stored in the `catalog_category_product` table in the field `position`.

Your script can go like this.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app ()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
umask(0);
$sku = $_GET['sku']; //not really safe to read from $_GET but for test purposes it will do.
$id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku); //get the product id.

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); //get an instance of the core resource
$connection = $resource->getConnection('core_write'); //get an instance of the write connection

$tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalog/category_product'); //this should add the prefix if you have one
$sql = "UPDATE {$tableName} SET `position` = 0 WHERE `product_id` = {$id}"; //set the position to 0 for the product in all the categories.
$connection->query($sql); //run the query
```

You may need to rebuild the indexes when you are done.

Comment: @Marius change `$q` to `$sql`.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman. damn copy/paste error. Thanks